# Extract a function parameters and allowed values

Tags: matlab

I've a `func1` with a list of parameters and posible values that can be added. I'm building a second function `func2`, which is based on the first one but add some new parameters and value. I would like to be able to add the `func1` parameters-values inside the `func2`. I know I could copy all the func1 file into the func2, but is there a better way arround? Is there a way to extract the parameters-values from a function?

Comment: does `func2` call `func1`? can you modify `func1`?

Comment: @m.s. func2 calls func1 and func1 cannot be modified

Comment: can you give a simple example what you try to achieve? is `func2` basically a wrapper function with the first `n` arguments being equal to `func1` and `n+1...m` arguments being added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using [`varargin`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html).

Example:

**func1.m**

```
% simple demo function, squares the 3 input arguments and returns a vector
function [ out ] = func1( in_1, in_2, in_3 )
out = [in_1, in_2, in_3];
out = out.*out;
end
```

**func2.m**

```
% this function adds some functionality to func1
% it needs 2 additional parameters
function [out] = func2(varargin)

if nargin ~=  5
    error('wrong number of arguments');
end

% call func1
out = func1(varargin{1:3});

% append data to output
out = [out, varargin{4:5}];
end
```

Demo output:

```
>>func2(1,2,3,4,5)

ans =

     1     4     9     4     5
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm asking to extract the parameters-value. For example corr(A,B,'Type','pearson') I would like to be able to extract all the possible 'parameters' and allowed values for the specific parameters. Hope you can understand, it's hard for me to explain.

Comment: @mat all possible parameters are implicitly encoded in `corr.m` (you can have a look at it using `open corr`). you cannot extract this information. even if you could, what would you do with this information?

Comment: func2 is an upgrade of func1, it supposed to use every parameter listed in func1and some new ones

Comment: @mat please be more specific, how does it "use" these parameters and the new ones?